# How can I determine if incoming request is for a controller (or any other resource for that matter)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, httprequest

I am attempting to help reduce when I hand out a database session (I am using NHibernate) so as to only hand one out if the incoming request is for a object that requires a session.

I know there is a way to get to information in the HttpApplication that would let me determine this, but I am not sure if it is as straight forward as I would like, or if I have to implement some logic based on the route request...etc.

Can someone recommend some way that I can review the request for determining this? I have reviewed the HttpApplication class and a number of properties/methods and assuming it is going to come down to somewhere in HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, but I thought I would see if there is a easy way of doing so.

Comment: there are ways to use IoC to inject an nhibernate session into your controllers.

Comment: example: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:nNn5JZb-DD0J:zvolkov.com/blog/post/2009/08/06/Easiest-way-to-hook-up-ASPNET-MVC-with-NHibernate.aspx+isession+nhibernate+castle+windsor+mvc&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: You are correct, and I am currently using StructureMap for doing just that.  This is not necessarily for getting the session to the controller. This is for taking advantage of the ManagedWebSessionContext of Nhibernate and binding and unbinding the current session through Nhibernate.  So in relation to my question, if I can determine if the request is for a resource that needs and Session, I would take the necessary steps to bind and unbind on BeginRequest/EndRequest from NHibernate.

Comment: If you are already using structure map, why do you need to use NHibernate's session context?  You can get your sessions lazily (eliminating the need for creating the session in BeginRequest) from StructureMap, then use ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects (); in EndRequest to handle session cleanup pretty trivially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from [Oyvind Valland's Blog](http://www.babel-lutefisk.net/) who was doing precisely what I was looking for and checking the incoming request for the resource requested to determine if a session was needed.  Julian Margarintescu makes a good point, but for an answer to the actual question in case it was needed for some other reason.

```
private static readonly string[] NoPersistenceFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".css", ".js", ".swf", ".xap", ".ico" };    
private static bool RequestMayRequirePersistence(HttpApplication httpApplication)
{
if (httpApplication == null)
return false;

HttpContext context = httpApplication.Context;
if (context == null)
return false;

string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
return fileExtension != null && Array.IndexOf(NoPersistenceFileExtensions, fileExtension.ToLower()) < 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a property: HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension - so you do not have to extract the file extension manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this post by Ayende about the [cost of opening a session](http://ayende.com/blog/4123/what-is-the-cost-of-opening-a-session). Empty/unused sessions are so light you can create them for any request, as they will not open a db connection.